# iOS Newstand Push Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, newsstand-kit

I have a newsstand app and am successfully sending the newsstand notification to trigger the download of new issues. This notification is using "content-available":1.

What I have noticed is that for those devices not connected to WiFi nothing happens. I understand that auto downloads are only for those devices connected to WiFi.

Push notification format is

```
{
  "aps":{
    "sound":"default",
    "content-available":1,
    "badge":0,
    "alert":"{{ title }} is now available"
},
  "issue":{
    "url":"{{ url }}",
    "name":"{{ title }}"
  }
}
```

I would at least like an alert to appear for those devices not connected to WiFi. Do I need to send another notification without "content-available":1?

For those devices connected to WiFi an alert is shown when the issue has downloaded. I would prefer not to send two notification if I can avoid it as this would then show two notification for WiFi connected devices (one to say there is a new issue and then another moments later to say that it has downloaded).

Comment: How do you expect the notification to come the device if its not connected to the internet? What usually happens is that the Apple's Push Notification Server waits until the required device is connected to the internet. If the specified time period expires, Apple sends back a notification to the server telling it, the device is not available.

Comment: I am also creating a newsstand app. I had a doubt that whether this push notification is send by apple? or we need to set a push notification server for sending this above payload?